# How much effective the below method is for Doubly Linked List Reversal

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have searched many algorithms online for reversing a doubly-linked list, but in most of them I have seen the steps are the same and after the reversal, only head pointer is being reassigned, there is no reassignment happening for the tail pointer.

So I have come up with the below method. But I'm not sure how much effective this method as per time complexity or space complexity.

Can anyone please help me with this? And also please suggest if any changes are required.

Below is the reversal method

```
if (head == null) {
    System.out.println("\nLinked List Is Empty");
}
else if (head.next == null) {
    printLinkedList();
}
else {
    ListNode start = head;
    ListNode end = tail;
    while (start!=end && start.next!=end.previous) {
        int temp = start.data;
        start.data = end.data;
        end.data = temp;
        start = start.next;
        end = end.previous;
    }
    if (start.next == end.previous) {
        int temp = start.data;
        start.data = end.data;
        end.data = temp;
    }
    printLinkedList();
}
```

This is the structure of ListNode Object from ListNode class

```
public class ListNode {

    int data;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode previous;

    private static ListNode head, tail;

    ListNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will fail on even-length lists. When you reach the middle of the list, start.next will be end, and end.previous will be start, so they will not be equal. The while loop will keep going until you reach the end of the list and get a null pointer exception. Instead, I think you meant:

```
while (start!=end && start.next!=end)
```

You will need to change the if statement accordingly (or it is possible to eliminate the if statement by changing the while loop condition, but I leave that to you).

As far as time and spatial complexity, you are doing as well as you can asymptotically at O(n) and O(1).